# Extract element using condition from 2d Lists

Tags: python-3.x, list

So, I faced a problem. Suppose I have two 2D lists.

> t=[[2, 'h'], [4, 'e'], [2, 'r']]

> t1=[[5, 'e'], [2, 'h'], [2, 'r'], [2, 'y']]

From these two lists, if second element of the sub-list is similar, I will extract based on the maximum based on the first element. If sub-list for first and second element is similar between two 2d lists, I will extract any of them.

So, my answer is =

> **['=:rr', '=:hh', '2:eeeee']**

Here 2 means I am getting it from B list and =: means I have that in both lists.

> **But the answer I want ['=:rr', '=:hh', '2:eeeee', '2:yy']**

So, I can't bring that **2:yy** using my code.

```
for x in t:
        for y in t1:
            if x[1]==y[1] and x[0]>y[0]:
                lst.append('1:'+str(x[1])*x[0])
            elif x[1]==y[1] and x[0]<y[0]:
                lst.append('2:'+str(y[1])*y[0])
            elif x[1]==y[1] and x[0]==y[0]:
                lst.append("=:"+str(y[1])*y[0])
```

thanks in advance

Comment: are the second elements of the sublists unique in A and B? In other words, can A be `[[1,'a'],[2,'a']]`?

Comment: yes I filtered out the duplicate. They are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the second elements are unique in each list, one option is to convert each list into a dictionary and analyze the intersecting keys:

```
dict_A = {k:v for v,k in A}
dict_B = {k:v for v,k in B}

out = []
for v in dict_A.keys() & dict_B.keys():
    a, b = dict_A[v], dict_B[v]
    if a > b:
        out.append(f'1:{v*a}')
    elif a == b:
        out.append(f'=:{v*a}')
    else:
        out.append(f'2:{v*b}')

for v in dict_A.keys() - dict_B.keys():
    out.append(f'1:{v*dict_A[v]}')

for v in dict_B.keys() - dict_A.keys():
    out.append(f'2:{v*dict_B[v]}')
```

Output:

```
['=:rr', '=:hh', '2:eeeee', '2:yy']
```